# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project hive-exec: There are test failures

Tags: eclipse, maven, hadoop, hive

When I try to build hive from source by following these commands:

```
$git clone https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hive.git

$cd hive

$mvn clean package -Pdist
```

I receive this errors after I run "`mvn clean package -Pdist`

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project hive-exec: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 

[ERROR] Please refer to /home/elbasir/hive/ql/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.

[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 

[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 

[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 

[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command

[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :hive-exec
```

Can anybody help to solve this? I have been searching the internet for a week to solve it but no success until now.

Here is the failure I got:

Running org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.repl.load.message.PrimaryToReplicaResourceFunctionTest

Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.573 sec <<< FAILURE! - in

org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.repl.load.message.PrimaryToReplicaResourceFunctionTest

createDestinationPath(org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.repl.load.message.PrimaryToReplicaResourceFunctionTest)  Time elapsed: 1.919 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError:

Expected: is "hdfs://somehost:9000/someBasePath/withADir/replicaDbName/somefunctionname/9223372036854775807/ab.jar"

but: was "hdfs://somehost:9000/someBasePath/withADir/replicadbname/somefunctionname/0/ab.jar" at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)

at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:865)

at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:832)

at 
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.repl.load.message.PrimaryToReplicaResourceFunctionTest.createDestinationPath(PrimaryToReplicaResourceFunctionTest.java:100)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)

at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:316)

at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:88)

at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:96)

at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:300)

at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)

at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)

at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)

at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)

at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)

at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:288)

at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:86)

at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)

at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:208)

at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)

at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:121)

at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:33)

at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:45)

at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:123)

at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:121)

at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)

at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)

at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)

at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)

at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)

at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)

at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)

at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)

at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)

Results :

Failed tests: 
PrimaryToReplicaResourceFunctionTest.createDestinationPath:100 Expected: is "hdfs://somehost:9000/someBasePath/withADir/replicaDbName/somefunctionname/9223372036854775807/ab.jar"

but: was "hdfs://somehost:9000/someBasePath/withADir/replicadbname/somefunctionname/0/ab.jar"

Tests run: 3305, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 14

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Reactor Summary:

[INFO]

[INFO] Hive ............................................... SUCCESS [  3.223 s]

[INFO] Hive Shims Common .................................. SUCCESS [ 10.496 s]

[INFO] Hive Shims 0.23 .................................... SUCCESS [  7.779 s]

[INFO] Hive Shims Scheduler ............................... SUCCESS [  3.569 s]

[INFO] Hive Shims ......................................... SUCCESS [  1.963 s]

[INFO] Hive Storage API ................................... SUCCESS [01:32 min]

[INFO] Hive Common ........................................ SUCCESS [01:07 min]

[INFO] Hive Service RPC ................................... SUCCESS [  5.318 s]

[INFO] Hive Serde ......................................... SUCCESS [03:32 min]

[INFO] Hive Standalone Metastore .......................... SUCCESS [ 37.830 s]

[INFO] Hive Metastore ..................................... SUCCESS [02:29 min]

[INFO] Hive Vector-Code-Gen Utilities ..................... SUCCESS [  0.298 s]

[INFO] Hive Llap Common ................................... SUCCESS [  7.068 s]

[INFO] Hive Llap Client ................................... SUCCESS [ 22.578 s]

[INFO] Hive Llap Tez ...................................... SUCCESS [ 16.250 s]

[INFO] Spark Remote Client ................................ SUCCESS [ 26.667 s]

[INFO] Hive Query Language ................................ FAILURE [  01:09 h]

[INFO] Hive Llap Server ................................... SKIPPED

[INFO] Hive Service ....................................... SKIPPED

[INFO] Hive Accumulo Handler .............................. SKIPPED

[INFO] Hive JDBC .......................................... SKIPPED

[INFO] Hive Beeline ....................................... SKIPPED

[INFO] Hive CLI ........................................... SKIPPED

[INFO] Hive Contrib ....................................... SKIPPED

[INFO] Hive Druid Handler ................................. SKIPPED

[INFO] Hive HBase Handler ................................. SKIPPED

[INFO] Hive JDBC Handler .................................. SKIPPED

[INFO] Hive HCatalog ...................................... SKIPPED

[INFO] Hive HCatalog Core ................................. SKIPPED

[INFO] Hive HCatalog Pig Adapter .......................... SKIPPED

[INFO] Hive HCatalog Server Extensions .................... SKIPPED

[INFO] Hive HCatalog Webhcat Java Client .................. SKIPPED

[INFO] Hive HCatalog Webhcat .............................. SKIPPED

[INFO] Hive HCatalog Streaming ............................ SKIPPED

[INFO] Hive HPL/SQL ....................................... SKIPPED

[INFO] Hive Llap External Client .......................... SKIPPED

[INFO] Hive Shims Aggregator .............................. SKIPPED

[INFO] Hive TestUtils ..................................... SKIPPED

[INFO] Hive Packaging ..................................... SKIPPED

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

Comment: Your unit tests are failing. If you observe the complete logs you would also see which tests. You can execute them in debugging mode to figure out why and then fix them.

Comment: Can you please explain more? I am new to maven and hive.

Comment: *maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project hive-exec: There are test failures.* means one or the other unit tests in your module are failing. If you look at the complete logs, it would also state which unit tests had failed.

Comment: These are the only errors I got, where can I find the complete logs?

Comment: The errors you shared are just a part of the build logs itself. These could not be all of it. Try going through each line after you execute `mvn clean package -Pdist`

Comment: I have edited my post by adding some of the logs.

Comment: And the updated logs doesnt' include any such errors as previously shared...Plus try debugging some stuff and share relevant bit to the question not all of it is supposed to be dumped in there.

Comment: When I execute mvn dependency::tree, it builds successfully. Any explanation why?

Comment: Since `mvn dependency:tree`  doesn't execute the `test` phase. You might want to read about maven lifecycle for that  https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Comment: I updated the post and added the failure task.

Comment: And you could clearly see what test is failing now. Just resolved that individually as you debug further.